getting an error while run flutter application (project :app > project :flutter_logs)
i'm getting the following error when trying to run a flutter app
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:1.0.20.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/umair13adil/RxLogs/1.0.20/RxLogs-1.0.20.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/umair13adil/RxLogs/1.0.20/RxLogs-1.0.20.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/umair13adil/RxLogs/1.0.20/RxLogs-1.0.20.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/umair13adil/RxLogs/1.0.20/RxLogs-1.0.20.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/umair13adil/RxLogs/1.0.20/RxLogs-1.0.20.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :flutter_logs

I have tried

delete pubspec.lock file,

run flutter clean,

run flutter pub get.

Changed the version to
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' in android/buildgradle



Some things you can do:

Double-check pubspec.yaml file for RxLogs. It might be a typo or incorrect.



Update Dependency Version



Manual Installation:

If the RxLogs package is not available on pub.dev, you might need to manually install it. This involves adding the repository URL and dependency information to your build.gradle file:
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  // Add the repository URL for RxLogs here if it's not on pub.dev
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs://The_version'
}



Update JitPack Repository:

If you’re using JitPack to resolve the dependency, ensure that the jitpack.io repository is added to your build.gradle file under the repositories section.
In your android/build.gradle (project-level):
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

Hope that helps

They released an new version of flutter_logs: ^2.2.0
in here they mentioned "Updated RxLogs version" after update this package its working fine.Thanks for your answer.
